# Is there any way that ng-model directive bind data after 10 seconds or after some time?

Tags: angularjs

I have a search field and i want that the binding of search textbox reflected after some time.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
<div ng-controller="appointment as vm">
Search By Description :  <input class="form-control" placeholder="search by    description" type="text" ng-model="vm.filterText" />
{{vm.filterText}} </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "bind data"? Would `$timeout(function() { vm.filterText = 'foo';}, 10)` be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ng-model-options directive will surely help you. You can update the binding after specified time or on blur event.

try this code

```
 Search By Description :  <input class="form-control" placeholder="search by description" type="text" ng-model="vm.filterText" ng-model-options={ debounce: 1000 } />
```

See example of ng-model-options   http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/try/kfPWlU4N

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-model-options` on your input field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.filterText" ng-model-options="{debounce: { 'default': 10000}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $interval in your directive. If you can share your directive as well, that will help.